# Quartz Job does not interrupt through scheduler.interrupt(jobKey) method

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Below the code which is executed through the cron and from this class, I'm calling my configuration class for manipulating the messages. while manipulating the message I want to interrupt this job through the rest API's.

```java
public class CronJob extends QuartzJobBean implements InterruptableJob
{
    private volatile boolean toStopFlag = true;

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean;
    @Autowired
    MessageConfiguration messageConfiguration;

    @Override
    public void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext)
            throws JobExecutionException
    {
        Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler();
        messageConfiguration.excuteMessageConfiguration(jobExecutionContext,
                scheduler);
    }

    @Override
    public void interrupt() throws UnableToInterruptJobException
    {
        System.out.println("Stopping thread... ");
        toStopFlag = false;
    }
}
```

************** Trying to interrupt the job*******

Here I'm trying to interrupt the job through the Rest API. Passing a job name statically.

```java
public void interruptJob() {
    List<JobExecutionContext> currentlyExecuting = scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
    for (JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext : currentlyExecuting) {     
        if(jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getKey().getName().equals("**JobName**")){
            Object result = scheduler.interrupt(jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getKey());
            System.out.println("stoppeed");
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is interrupt method is executed but the job is running continuously.

Helping hand will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, @samabcde for adding the tag.

Comment: I didn't see how you use `toStopFlag`, and this example class [DumbInterruptableJob](https://github.com/Flipkart/quartz/blob/master/distribution/examples/src/main/java/org/quartz/examples/example7/DumbInterruptableJob.java) may helps.